# T- SQL usage of @$

Tags: t-sql

I joined this new project and found a different way of declaring local vars in SQL Server Stored Procedures as

```
DECLARE @$prog VARCHAR(50),
        @$errno INT
```

I have always used `@` to declare local variables in T-SQL,
wondering when to use `@$`?

Please guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has no special meaning, the $-sign just happens to be legal inside an identifier. See [the MSDN page on identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx).